# Windows two keyboards mapped differently

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

With Win10, I have two keyboards and would like to use keyboard #1 as usual and keyboard #2 mapped in another way. Is it possible to hack Windows so that e.g. Q on keyboard #1 emits a different character or modifier code than keyboard #2? Currently the two keyboards are considered equal.

Possible use case: I have a separate numeric keyboard, and would like to use key 1,2,3 instead of MMB actions for pan, rotate, zoom in Blender, as the MMB button push or drag is really damaging my hand. (I would use the standard navigation feature on my normal keyboard, that also includes a numeric keyboard).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Arn8ExQ2Gjg should help.

Comment: @VividKraig: Wow, this looks promising! Let me try this ;-).